# How to cite a motion picture or TV show?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, natbib

I want to cite motion pictures and TV series using commands such as `\citep{}` and a external bibtex file. What is the proper way?

I'm using the `natlib` package and the configuration commands `\citestyle{chicago}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. My attempt was writing this to the external `.bib` file:

```
@misc{himym,
    title={How {I} met your mother},
    year=2005,
    note={Premiered on CBS}
}
```

But the output of `\citep{}` will be `him`, that is, the first three letters of the cite key. I was expecting something like

> *How I met your mother*, 2005.

The ideal output on the references would be

> *How I met your mother*, 2005. Premiered on CBS.

`natbib`'s manual say that, in cases where there isn't an author or year, it uses the `key` field to cite an entry. By doing so, `\citep{himym}` will only give me what's inside `key`, without the year.

Comment: The `key` field is an *extra* field that you can add to a record.  It's not the same as the Cite Key.

Comment: That's true. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres's a solution using [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) -- with this package, the title replaces a missing author for author-year-styles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{himym,
    title={How {I} met your mother},
    year= {2005},
    note={Premiered on CBS},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite{himym}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: After managing to install `biblatex`, this solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much.